# Django drf-yasg ViewSet Error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using ReadOnlyModelViewSet for my API and I keep on getting an error:

My ViewSet:

```
class CartItemViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    """
    ViewSet for Cart functions
    """
    queryset = CartItem.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CartItemSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
```

Serializer:

```
class CartItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # product = UserSerializer(read_only=True)

    model = CartItem
    fields = ['uuid', 'product', 'quantity', 'cart_item_price']
```

Error Message:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/drf_yasg/inspectors/field.py", line 102, in make_schema_definition
for property_name, child in serializer.fields.items():
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Answer (score 2):

The **`model`** and **`fields`** should be inside your  **`Meta`** class

```
class CartItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CartItem
        fields = ['uuid', 'product', 'quantity', 'cart_item_price']
```